# Making HTTPS POST call is not working in AWS production env

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, zoho

Our application will integrate customer data to zoho crm. We developed a lambda function in nodejs which uses ZohoCrm Library to call zoho api.  All works fine in development environment. But when we deploy the code to lambda function which throws error "post err: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT". However this will not throw error consistently sometimes worked perfectly and sometimes throws error. We could not figure out the exact root cause.

zoho crm uses oauth 2.0. When the zohocrm client generating access token by post request throws error "post err: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT".

AWS Architecture for lambda function:

Lambda function is inside our VPC. We properly configured subnets which can communicate to internet (public subnet).Also security groups properly configured.

Lambda Memory 256 MB
Time out 3 mins (We tried to increase time out even then the same issue exist.)

Nodejs version 10.16.0
zcrmsdk version 0.0.15

Comment: Are you sure the security groups are properly configured? That'd be my usual suspect in a case like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gricey. As the security groups are configured correctly, lambda function works perfectly 70% of the cases only fails 30%. That's why we could not figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is because of subnet association. When we launch lambda inside vpc, we have to associate private subnet with NAT gateway to call the internet. I configured public subnet for my lambda function. Now i changed it all working fine.

Thank you all for the support.